# create html through C# code in PageLoad

Tags: html, asp.net, conditional-statements, pageload

Basically, I have a "*Posts*" DataTable with multiple rows.
Each row contains fields like "*UserID*", "*PostBody*", "*PostDate*", "*UploadedFileID*" etc.

What I'm trying to achieve is a "News" page, where users can see all the posts from the DataTable.

So if I have 5 rows, i want for each row to have an HTML Structure like:

```
<div id="post">
    <h3>User name (based on the UserID row)</h3>
    <div id="postBody">
        bla bla bla whatever the user posted
    </div>
    <a href="(link to the posted file)">
        <img src="something" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm thinking that inside the .aspx file, in the PageLoad event I have to make a while loop, like:

```
while (there are posts in the posts table)
    write html;
```

How do I add HTML-building conditions, and more importantly, paging?

Thanks,
Tudor.

Comment: see gridview,listview they re for that only. If you want to do it yourself make a usercontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the several data binding controls and put your html structure into the template.

Refer: [Asp.net DataBound controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Ones like the Repeater or ListView should give you what you want.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
  DataSourceID="PostsDataSource" >
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div id="post">
      <h3>User name (based on the UserID row)</h3>
      <div id="postBody">
        <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="Server"
                   Text='<%#Eval("PostBody") %>' />
      </div>
      <a href="(link to the posted file)">
        <img src="something" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

ListView1.DataSource =

The advantage of using a data binding control is that asp.net will manage the paging and value binding.